# Applying a function over a list, can't extract desired parts from each element's name

Tags: r

I wrote the following function:

```
require(data.table)
missing.na <- function(x) {
  table <- table(x, useNA = "always")
  df.table <- as.data.frame(table)
  data.frame <- data.frame("Present" = c(gsub("^.*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(x))), "Present", sum(subset(df.table, !is.na(df.table[, 1]))[, 2])), 
                           "Missing" = c(NA, "Missing", sum(subset(df.table, is.na(df.table[, 1]))[, 2])))
  return(data.frame)
}
```

Which I need to apply over some vectors in the following data frame and combine the outputs into a new data frame (example data):

```
df <- data.frame("s1" = c("1", "2", "3", NA, NA, NA), "s1a" = c(NA, "3", NA, "5", "6", "5"), "s1b" = c("2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2"))
```

The following works:

```
Output1 <- rbindlist(list(missing.na(df$s1), missing.na(df$s1a), missing.na(df$s1b)))
```

I get the name of the vector after the '$' operator returned where it should (every 3 rows, first column).

However, I know I should be able to simplify this by just applying the function over the list of the vectors (actual project has many more vectors of differing lengths).  However, when I try that:

```
Varlist <- list(df$s1, df$s1a, df$s1b)
Output2 <- rbindlist(lapply(Varlist, missing.na))
```

I get 'X[[i]]' instead of the part of the name of each vector that I want.  How can I apply my function over my list of vectors and get the same output in 'Output2' that I get in 'Output1'?

Comment: What is the desired output here? The `missing.na` function seems to return a data.frame with very weird names at present.

Comment: Are you sure you shared the same `missing.na` function you are using? Because `names(missing.na(df$s1))` for me returns: `[1] "c.gsub...............deparse.substitute.x......Present...sum.subset.df.table.."
[2] "c.NA...Missing...sum.subset.df.table..is.na.df.table...1......"`

Comment: Rewrote the function to give the data frame more manageable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you are after with a few tidyverse functions (from tibble and `purrr`. First, i'd change your function to accept a name parameter rather than requiring a deparse

```
missing.na <- function(x, name=deparse(substute(x))) {
  table <- table(x, useNA = "always")
  df.table <- as.data.frame(table)
  data.frame <- data_frame("Present"=c(gsub("^.*\\$", "", name), "Present", sum(subset(df.table, !is.na(df.table[, 1]))[, 2])), 
                           "Missing"=c(NA, "Missing", sum(subset(df.table, is.na(df.table[, 1]))[, 2])))
  return(data.frame)
}
```

Then you can use `lst()` to create a named list for you, and pipe that to `map2_dfr()` to call your function with two parameters and collect those into a data.frame

```
tibble::lst(df$s1, df$s1a, df$s1b) %>% 
    purrr::map2_dfr(., names(.), missing.na)

This returns

  Present Missing
    <chr>   <chr>
1      s1    <NA>
2 Present Missing
3       3       3
4     s1a    <NA>
5 Present Missing
6       4       2
7     s1b    <NA>
8 Present Missing
9       6       0
```